# Better way declare a controller in AngularJS module?

Tags: angularjs

I had observed that inside AngularSeed, some controllers have the following format:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {

  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);
```

whereas, some controllers have the following syntax:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    } }]);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    } }]);
```

Which is a good practice for a project in production?
Also, is there any performance difference between these two approaches?

Comment: [This style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) should be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no **difference in the performance** among these two syntaxes. 
But it is recommended that we use the second approach.

Remember that angular.module() returns a module object. This would expose the functions of controllers, filters, services, and directive registrations. 
Now each of these functions would return the same module, so we are talking about the same reference. This is similar to a builder pattern.

According to [Angular Best Practice for App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) (Public), it is recommended that angular.module() should not be called more than once, and other files and modules should not modify the same. 
For this reason, the latter is always recommended.

The logic is simple:
Expose your module as a global variable, and let other files add on to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

if your project is very big i suggest you this syntax...

```
var controller = function (scope) {
};

controller.$inject = ["$scope"];

app.controller("appCtrl", controller);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you include only a single component per file, there is rarely a need to introduce a variable for the module. Instead, use the simple getter syntax. When using a module, using chaining with the getter syntax avoids variables collisions or leaks.

From [John Papa's Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/50b8e76b8fb03a93e6d2acf55cf85ed255da21d3/a1/README.md#style-y022):

> ```
> /* avoid */
> var app = angular.module('app');
> app.controller('SomeController' , SomeController);
>
> function SomeController() { }
> ```
>
> ```
> /* recommended */
> angular
> .module('app')
> .controller('SomeController' , SomeController);
>
> function SomeController() { }
> ```

Comment: introducing a variable is hardly an expensive operation and a counter argument could be made regarding chaining.

Comment: Provide [your source](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules), else it is plagiarism.